# mootools form json post request

Tags: php, javascript, html, mootools

i want to to a `request.JSON`  on a dynamic form.

is it possible to POST the complete form via a form id ?

```
<table>
<form id="form">
        <tr>
          <td>username</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>password</td>
          <td><input type="password" id="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" id="go" value="go"/></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

and on the script side:

```
$('go').addEvent('click',function( event )
{
  event.stop();
   var myForm = document.id('form');

  var request= new Request.JSON (
  {
    url: 'check_login.php',
    method: 'post',
    data:
    {
     form: myForm
    },
    onSuccess: function( response ) 
    {
      if ( response.status )
      {
        document.location = "home.php"   
      }
      else
      {
        $('response').addClass('error');
        $('response').set('html', response.message);
      }
    },

});
     request.send();
```

and in the php script i want to check via the $_POST variable.
but i cannot find a method to do it like this. actually im gettinh nothing.

greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, look at this link where it shows how to do it:

http://demos111.mootools.net/Ajax.Form

It basically selects the form via your ID, add a listener to submit event and when it comes it sends all the form the way you are looking for :-)